# Add element on top of image dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, insert

When I click the button, it has to add an object (img, p) inside the div and the image with border and then take the position of that object, (x, y coordinates).

[image: screenshot]

How can I make this using JQuery?

**HTML**:

```
<div style="height: 440px; border: 1px solid; width: 880px; margin-top: 50px; margin-left: -12px;">
    <img id="imagem-principal" width="880" height="440" class="custom_media_image attachment-post-thumbnail" src="<?= $segunda_imagem; ?>">
</div>
```

Comment: Can you make a demo on jsFiddle and include the JS/jQuery and CSS?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3wLhvg1x/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a button create a new `<img>` and place it on top, add the following styles:

```
div {
    position: relative;
}
img:not(#imagem-principal) {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Then, you can add an `onclick` listener in jQuery:

```
$("#addImg").click(function() {

    // set x and y to what you want
    var xCoor = // X_COORDINATE;
    var yCoor = // Y_COORDINATE;

    var newImg = $("<img src='/* IMAGE_URL */' />");
    newImg.css({left: xCoor, top: yCoor});
    $("div").append(newImg);
});
```

This will create a new image with the given `x` and `y` coordinates *on top of* the other image.

See working example on [JSFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/3wLhvg1x/1/).

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you so much!